# How can I un-ignore people within a G+ Community?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-communities

I have a medium sized private G+ Community to manage.

As only a fraction of the requests to join actually gets processed, I batch ignore join requests every now and then to clean up the list.

Now a person who I previously ignored, requested to join again. This time I want to approve that person, but it seems like the community kept the ignore status and I can't see the request. I got a notification on my profile, but the person did not show up in the "Waiting for approval" list.

How can I fix this?

Comment: note: I sent this person an invite and it worked, but I need a better approach to manage ignored users for the future.